# Python database handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

There are databases present in xamp but after connecting with python file, the python file shows no databse, while xamp and my file r properly connected with MySQL. `Connector.Connect()` command.

Comment: Please include more detail in your question.

Comment: When i gave any query it shows none.

Comment: Mycursor. Execute("show data bases" ).       
 the output of this command is also "none" while many databases are present in xamp

Comment: Please edit your question to incldue these details and any relevant code.